# Different logarithm basis equivalence in big-O notation

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

Often, when I encounter big-O notation during computations, the basis of the logarithm is omitted. Is there an error, or is it in some sense irrelevant? Or am I missing something?

For instance, $\log_2 n$ is often indicated as $O(\log n)$. However, sometimes I also see it as $O(\log_2 n)$ so this is confusing me.

Comment: You need to be careful. O isn’t sensitive to change if logarithm base, as the answers say, but sometimes $\log_2$ represents the twice-iterated logarithm $\log\log$ and that’s especially likely if it’s inside a big O.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is due to the property of logarithm's basis.

From the basis change formula of logarithms, you get:
$$\log_a n = \frac{\log_b n}{\log_b a} \, $$

and $\log_b a$ is a constant with respect to your variable $n$. Thus, $O(\log_a n)=O(\frac{\log_b n}{\log_b a}) = O(\log_b n)$.

This means that you can either write $O(\log_2 n)$ or omit it and write $O(\log n)$ (which usually refers to the natural basis $e$, also written as $\ln n$), because it makes no difference.

Answer (score 6):

The difference between $\log_2$ and any of the other commonly used logs (base 10 or base $e$) is just multiplication by some order $1$ constant so that might be why it isn't so relevant.

$$\log_{10}x = \frac{\log_n x}{\log_n10}$$ and for $n=e,2$ the factor on the bottom is negligible ish.

Answer (score 5):

This answer isn't going to be fun, but I'm going to be pedantic here to justify why it's okay to ignore constants in big-$O$ by using the formal definition.

[Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations): Let $f$ and $g$ be functions that map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. We say that $f \in O(g)$ ("$f$ is in big-$O$ of $g$") iff: $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \left[n > n_0 \Rightarrow f(n) < k \cdot g(n)\right]$.

In English, that says there exists a constant $k$ and a constant $n_0$ such that every $n$ greater than $n_0$ will imply that $f(n) < k \cdot g(n)$. The constant $k$ controls how much to scale the function $g$, and the constant $n_0$ controls how many small numbers to ignore.

---

We know from the change-of-base formula that $\displaystyle\log_b a = \frac{\ln a}{\ln b}$.

Claim: For any $a, b > 1$, we have that $f \in O(\log_a n)$ if and only if $f \in O(\log_b n)$.

Given on the left side that $f \in O(\log_a n)$, we know that there must exist constants $k$ and $n_0$ to satisfy the big-$O$ definition. To make it satisfy the definition for $f \in O(\log_b n)$ on the right side, we take $k' = k \frac{\ln b}{\ln a}$ and the same $n_0$, and the formula will work out.

In conclusion, it is redundant for big-$O$ purposes to write the base of the logarithm as long as it greater than one. So writing a vague-looking $f \in O(\log n)$ loses no information.